# Python two csv with similar content in one dataframe with diffrent Dates and diffrent length

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to add two csv's to one dataframe. The 2 Dataframes are similar but not the same. The Date is about 10 min apart. The length can be diffrent two.
I need a left joint but how can I make wehen ther is no data it should be replaced with a zero or a null?

out1.csv:

```
date,speed
2021-10-03 02:00:01,5.0
2021-10-03 02:00:02,5.2
2021-10-03 02:00:03,5.1
```

out2.csv:

```
date,curret
2021-10-03 02:00:02,32.012
2021-10-03 02:00:03,32.12
2021-10-03 02:00:04,32.5
```

As a outpu I need a dataframe something like that:

```
date,speed,current
2021-10-03 02:00:01,5.0,null
2021-10-03 02:00:02,5.2,32.012
2021-10-03 02:00:03,5.1,32.12
2021-10-03 02:00:04,null,32.5
```

Answer (score -1):

There is `on` parameter in the `join()` method.
As per [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html),

> Another option to join using the key columns is to use the on
> parameter. DataFrame.join always uses other’s index but we can use any
> column in df. This method preserves the original DataFrame’s index in
> the result.

```
df.join(other.set_index('key'), on='key')
  key   A    B
0  K0  A0   B0
1  K1  A1   B1
2  K2  A2   B2
3  K3  A3  NaN
4  K4  A4  NaN
5  K5  A5  NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

Use outer join -
`df1.merge(df2, how="outer")`

See documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)